# Calling SQL Server Scalar Function in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I created a scalar function in SQL Server with 2 parameters. Everything works, and when adding it to the WPF project, it is displayed when adding it (I do it through ADO). When everything was added, then it simply does not exist. There are some other ways or something else. Thanks in advance.

[image]

when I use this code, it returns a value that matches. Everything works correctly. But now how can I call it from the WPF in the code itself. I know stored procedure as, and as function without concept, it simply is not shown there.

[image]

Вот скалярная функция в  SQL-Server

[image]

Here it is in VS 2019

[image]

But when I want to call it, it's just not there ...

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: In WPF, I connect through ADO, all tables are visible, all chronic procedures are also visible, but it sees the function, but when it is called, it seems to be absent.

Comment: there is no call to this function. Procedures are all visible which I created, I can choose and everything works. But even VS does not see the function.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are connected to the right database?

Comment: yes, it seems yes, there I have only one database, and now it sees everything, but what would this scalar function be, no.

Comment: And what is your `Context` is it using Entity Framework? If so have you re-synced it with your database?